# Adding Slide-to-Anchor to Hide effect

Tags: jquery, scroll, hide, effects, show

In jQuery: I'd like to create an link to on click shows a hidden div (got that working by now) but also slides to it with a smooth-scroll effect. How do I combine the two?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you talking about scrolling the viewable pane down to the location of the div?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you meant: I'm talking about a click event that would trigger the following:

1) SHOW a hidden div
2) SCROLL to an #anchor on the top of that div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin to give smooth scoll effects.

Demo [here.](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Comment: Can the click event for both scrollTo and Show share the same ID?

Answer (score 1):

It’s a oneliner but can add a [really nice effect](http://djpate.com/portfolio/scrollTop/).

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
}

<script>
   goToByScroll("theIdIWantToGoTo");
</script>
```

http://djpate.com/2009/10/07/animated-scroll-to-anchorid-function-with-jquery/